# when i install my feature into odl, there is a problem aboule:zodiac.springsource.com: Name or service not known

Tags: osgi, opendaylight

I tried to install to a distribution odl (0.6.4-Carbon). But i obtain an error when I run this command "`feature:install odl-topo（my feature）`".

I have copied the files to '`/system/com/sunminming/topo`', and run "f`eature:repo-add mvn:……`"

> opendaylight-user@root>feature:install odl-topo
>   Error executing command: Error resolving artifact org.opendaylight.yangtools:features-yangtools:xml:features:1.1.2-Carbon: Could not transfer artifact org.opendaylight.yangtools:features-yangtools:xml:features:1.1.2-Carbon from/to gemini (http://zodiac.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/): zodiac.springsource.com: Name or service not known

Comment: Can you give the full command of feature:repo-add and the contents of it?

Comment: The full command is “feature:repo-add mvn:com.sunminming.topo/topo-features/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/xml/features”, the contents is the mvn path of my project in file "/topo/karaf/target/assembly/etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg"

Answer (score 0):

The repository zodiac.springsource.com seems to be down. I guess one of the features you reference uses the zodiac repo. If this is not in your feature file then the odl community might have to adapt their feature.